Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a reducibly finite group?
A group $G$ is reducibly finite if, for every $g$ in $G$ different from the identity, there exists a finite group $H$ and a group homomorphism $\theta:G\rightarrow H$ such that $\theta(g)$ still isn't the identity.
For example, if $n$ is an element of $\mathbb{Z}$ different from zero, then the quotient map $\theta:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/(\vert n\vert+1)\mathbb{Z}$ takes $n$ to a non-zero element, so proving that $\mathbb{Z}$ is reducibly finite.
Is this also true for $\mathbb{Q}$?
I have no idea if this is true. My intuition is that if $H$ is a quotient of $\mathbb{Q}$, then $H$ should be infinite, proving that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't reducibly finite, but I'm not completely sure on this (I failed to prove it after a long time). Does $\mathbb{Q}$ have any finite quotient?
I haven't been able to find any references either. Any help would be appreciated.
Edit: In the example, I originally took the quotient to be $\mathbb{Z}/(n+1)\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}/(\vert n\vert+1)\mathbb{Z}$, which would make this false for $n=-1$. Thanks for pointing it out.

In your example, what happens if $n=-1$?

Sorry, I meant the quotient onto $\mathbb{Z}/{(\vert n\vert+1)}\mathbb{Z}$.

The standard term for this is residually finite, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not residually finite. To see this show that, in order:

$\mathbb{Q}$ is divisible,
Every quotient of a divisible group is divisible, and
The only divisible finite group is the trivial group.


Thanks! Sorry for the mistake, I was thinking about this in other language and made a mistake re-translating it into english. Thanks for the answer, it is what i needed.
